# Private array of adjacent node addresses in C++

Tags: c++, graph, edges

////EDIT #2: Deleted all the previous info and just post the working code now. Previous question became too lengthy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node{
    T data;
    vector<Node<T>*> adjacent;
    friend class Graph;
    public:
        int n;  
        Node(T initData) : data(initData), n(0){}
        void addAdjacent(Node<T>& other){
            adjacent.push_back(&other);
            n++;
        }
        T getData(){
            return data;
        }
        Node<T>* getEdge(int edgeNum){
            return adjacent[edgeNum];
        }
};
template<class T>
class GraphCl{
    int n;
    vector<Node<T>*> nodes;
    T input;
    public:
        GraphCl(int size): n(size){
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                cout << "Enter data for node " << i << ": ";
                cin >> input; 
                nodes.push_back(new Node<T>(input)) ;
            }
        }
    void addEdge(int baseNode, int edgeNode){
        nodes[baseNode]->addAdjacent(*nodes[edgeNode]);
    }
    void printGraph(){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            Node<T> *base = nodes[i];
            cout << "Data of node " << i <<": "<< base->getData() <<endl;
            for (int j=0;j<base->n;j++){
                cout << "Edge #"<< j+1 << " of node " << i << ": " << base->getEdge(j) <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    GraphCl<int> *myGraph = new GraphCl<int>(5);
    myGraph->addEdge(0,1);
    myGraph->addEdge(0,2);
    myGraph->addEdge(0,3);
    myGraph->addEdge(0,4);
    myGraph->addEdge(3,1);
    myGraph->addEdge(3,0);
    myGraph->printGraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter data for node 0: -34
Enter data for node 1: 12
Enter data for node 2: 56
Enter data for node 3: 3
Enter data for node 4: 23
Data of node 0: -34
Edge #1 of node 0: 0x7fbeebd00040
Edge #2 of node 0: 0x7fbeebd00080
Edge #3 of node 0: 0x7fbeebe00000
Edge #4 of node 0: 0x7fbeebd000d0
Data of node 1: 12
Data of node 2: 56
Data of node 3: 3
Edge #1 of node 3: 0x7fbeebd00040
Edge #2 of node 3: 0x7fbeebd00000
Data of node 4: 23
```

As you can see this simple implementation is working. I decided to just cut out all the complicated stuff and keep it simple with dynamically changing vectors. Obviously less efficient but I can work from here on. Since I am new with C++ the previous implementation just got my head spinning 360 degrees thinking about where all the pointers to pointers went, without even thinking about memory allocation. The above code basically is a directed graph that is very sensitive to input errors, so I got to work on it still.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Thanks! Great help. It give me heaps of insight in what I was actually doing. Im quite new to C++.

Comment: A few other issues with your code, btw:

If ```x``` is of type ```T*```, then ```x[n]``` (where ```n``` is of integral type), gives you a reference (```T&```) to an element at the position "```x + n```". So your ```->``` in ```addEdges``` should be a ```.``` instead.

Comment: Also, ```Node *adjacent``` has two possible uses: an array of actual nodes, physically located somewhere, or a pointer to a location of a single node. If you want an array of pointers to nodes, then its either ```Node *adjacent[]``` (fixed size array), or```Node **adjacent```, which is a pointer to a location in memory which includes pointers to nodes.

Comment: In addition, ```new Node[n]``` in the ```Graph``` constructor might not be what you want. This will fail to compile because your ```Node``` has no default constructor, and initializing an array (in some C++ versions) will default-initialize each member.

Comment: Once you have an implementation that actually compiles, an awesome experience would be to post it on the Code Review Stack Exchange site. You'll get a lot of help and insights.

Comment: Likely unrelated, but why are you allocating a Note<T> on the stack using ```new``` then pushing it to a vector? Pushing a node on a vector will copy it to the vector. The heap-allocated node is not being deallocated and causes a memory leack. Why not just put the node on the stack by doing ```Node<T> myNode(input);``` and then pushing ```myNode``` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering the updated question*

There are a few issues with putting `Node`s directly in a `std::vector` in your case.

Using a `std::vector` is great for many things, but if you are doing that, you should make sure not to take pointers to vectors. Remember, pointers refer to exact addresses in memory of where an object is stored. A `vector` is a growable container of elements. To store elements contiguously, the vector allocates a bunch of memory, puts objects there, and if it has to grow, it will allocate more memory and move the objects around. It is essentially doing something similar to what you are doing in your `Node` and grow (except, in its case, its explicitly destroying the objects before freeing the old memory).

Notice that your `Grow` function allocates new memory and copies the pointers. Simlarly, vectors can allocate new memory and copy the data over. This means that holding pointers to data in a vector is bad. **The only guarantee a `vector` gives you is that its data will continue to be accessible using array-style indexing, find, iteration, etc., not that the data will exist in the same memory location forever**.

---

**Explaining the exact bug you are seeing**

The vector is invoking a [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/). The default copy constructor copies every field one-by-one. This is not what you want in the case of `Node`, because then you have two vectors that think they own the `Node** adjacent` memory location. When the first node (the old copy) is being destroyed, it will free its adjacent nodes (which is the same as the copy's adjacent node). When the new copy is being destroyed, it will attempt to free that same memory location, but it is already freed. You also have the problem here that, if you attempted to access the memory after it has been destroyed in the first node, you'll be in trouble.

**Why was this bug showing up when you were only adding nodes?**

When a vector grows to a certain amount, it needs to resize. In most implementation, the process is roughly:

1. Allocate a bunch more memory (usually twice the old capacity)
2. Invoke the copy constructor to copy elements from the old location to the new location
3. Destroy the elements in the old location (say, by explicitly calling the destructor)
4. Insert the new element in the new location

Your bug is showing up because of steps 2 and 3, basically.

**Fixing this particular bug**

For your case, the default copy constructor is no good because copying a node should meet a **deep** copy of all of the data. A regular copy in C++ will copy all of the data on the class or struct itself. If the data is a pointer, then the pointer is copied, not the thing its pointing to.

Override the copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
    Node(const Node<T>& other) : data(other.data), capacity(other.capacity), n(other.n) {
        adjacent = reinterpret_cast<Node**>(malloc(capacity * sizeof(Node**)));
        memcpy(adjacent, other.adjacent, capacity * sizeof(Node**));
    }

    Node<T>& operator= (const Node<T>& other) {
        data = other.data;
        capacity = other.capacity;
        n = other.n;
        adjacent = reinterpret_cast<Node**>(malloc(capacity * sizeof(Node**)));
        memcpy(adjacent, other.adjacent, capacity * sizeof(Node**));
    }
```

**A Bigger Problem**

A bigger problem with your code is that the use of an `std::vector` *and* pointers to its elements. Choose one of:

- Use a fixed-sized array (which is stable in memory), and point to these objects
- Forget about pointers altogether, and make your adjacent list a list of indices into the vector (its less performant as you need to go through the vector each time, but that likely won't be your bottleneck for now)

Answer (score 1):

**Accessibility**

Regarding the accessibility of the array to the `Graph`, the closest thing to the current implementation is to declare declare `Graph` as a friend of `Node`. Simply add:

```
friend Graph;
```

To the end of the `Node` class declaration.

That said, making a class as a `friend` is sometimes a sign that the API you defined isn't exactly right if classes need to know too much about each others' implementation details. You can alternatively provide an interface for `Node` such as:

```
void AddAdjacent(Node* other);
```

**Managing Adjacent Nodes**

If you want your `adjacent` pointer array to be growable, then you are basically re-creating `std::vector`, so I would suggest using `std::vector<Node*>`. Initializing a vector with the default (empty) constructor would take care of it, and a `nodes[baseNode]->adjacent.push_back(...)` would be all you need in `addEdges`.

If memory is not a consideration and you have a maximal number of nodes in the graph, you can instantiate a constant-sized array.

If you really don't want to use `std::vector`, but you actually want a growable array of pointers, then you'll have to manage your own `malloc` and `free` calls. I'll write something up to that effect, but my advice is to just go ahead with `vector`.

In case you are curious, the array approach would look something like:

```
template<class T>
class Node : public Graph{
    Node **adjacent; //pointer to array of POINTERS TO adjacent Nodes
    int n;
    size_t capacity;
    T data;
    friend Graph;

public:
    Node(T initData) : data(initData), capacity(8) {
        n = 0;
        adjacent = reinterpret_cast<Node**>(malloc(capacity * sizeof(Node**)));
    }
    ~Node() {
        free(adjacent);
    }
    void Grow() {
        size_t new_cap = base.capacity * 2;
        Node<int> **copy = reinterpret_cast<Node<int>**>(malloc(new_cap * sizeof(Node**)));
        memcpy(copy, base.adjacent, base.capacity); // copy and adjacent are non-overlapping, we can use memcpy
        free(base.adjacent);
        base.adjacent = copy;
        base.capacity = new_cap;
    }
};
```

And the insertion:

```
Node<T>& base = nodes[baseNode];
Node<T>* edge = &(nodes[edgeNode]);
if (base.capacity == base.n) base.Grow();
base.adjacent[base.n++] = edge;
```

Comment: Note that I updated my code to add ``` * sizeof(Node**)``` in the malloc calls. That is unrelated to your bug, but its a serious issue in the code.